# PHP Parse Error: script can not get data from form

Tags: php, html

I tried to collect data from this form,as a quiz:

```
        <form action="quiz.php" method = "post" id = "questions" name = "quiz">
            <label>This is a quiz:</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name = "vote1" value = "Yes"/><label>Yes</label> 
            <input type="radio" name = "vote1" value = "No"/><label>No</label> 
            <button type = "submit" name="send">Submit</button>
       </form>
```

And I sent it to this php script:

```
<html>
  <?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])){
  if (isset($_POST["quiz"])){
  if (isset($_POST['vote1'])){
    if ($_POST['vote1'] === "Yes"){
      echo "Yes,that is the answer.";
}else{
  echo "Yes,that is the answer";
};
}};};
  ?>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

But it didn't generate any HTML...
Although you can see in the url,that it definetely tried to pick up data:

```
http://localhost/php/quiz.php?vote1=Yes&send=
```

But it didn't really send data and I don't know what to do in that case,can anyone help me?...

Comment: What line causes the "_PHP Parse error_" you mentioned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the form `method` was GET you would get a querystring  as described but the above form uses POST so that would not happen. The only form element of interest in the POST array really is `vote1` so ensure that is present using `isset` - the other items such as the button or the form name ( ? which won't be there, ever! ) are not relevant.

A `label` element should be associated with a form element in one of two ways: either using the `for=ID_of_element` type syntax or by having the element as a child, as below.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Quiz></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="quiz.php" method="post" id="questions" name="quiz">
            <h1>This is a quiz:</h1>
            <label><input type="radio" name="vote1" value="Yes"/>Yes</label> 
            <label><input type="radio" name="vote1" value="No"/>No</label> 
            <button type = "submit" name="send">Submit</button>
        </form>
        <?php
            if( isset( $_POST['vote1'] ) ){
                $msg='';
                switch( strtolower( $_POST['vote1'] ) ){
                    case 'yes':$msg='Yes,that is the answer.';break;
                    case 'no':$msg='Sorry, that is not correct';break;
                }
                echo $msg;
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It was not displaying output because of   if (isset($_POST["quiz"]))

Below code of yours will work, and will display you echo result.

```
<html>
<?php
if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

    if (isset($_POST['vote1'])) {
      if ($_POST['vote1'] == "Yes") {
        echo "Yes,that is the answer.";
      } else {
        echo "Yes,that is the answer";
      };
    }

};
?>

<body>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: ,Thank you for your answer, I ended up using the code of Professor Abronsius,I think your answer would have worked too! :)